# TypeError-For resolving a Type error

Tags: python

I am trying to find a bug in the function:

```
def buggy_join(input, sep=","):
   return sep.join(input)
```

When I tried to call the function using:

```
buggy_join(range(6))
```

it is showing type error stating expected String int found.
How can I solve it.Does the `join` function work only with `basestring` type??

```
input = list(itertools.chain(*enumerate("abc")))
buggy_join(input, ".")
```

It was causing  the same error even for the above call.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of this exercise that you figure out how to debug it yourself?

Comment: Yes ,I think I reached close but,how can I change it to string??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have correctly figured out the problem, here is one solution:

```
def not_buggy_join(input, sep=","):
    return sep.join(map(str, input))
```

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), `map(function, iterable)` will

> Apply `function` to every item of `iterable` and return a list of the results.

In this case, it converts everything to a `str`. To use your own example:

```
>>> not_buggy_join(itertools.chain(*enumerate("abc")))
'0,a,1,b,2,c'
```

Comment: I thought the same answer but,doubted its correctness thankyou..!

Comment: If you thought of it, why not test it before coming to SO?